# How to detect the orientation change event in device in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, orientation, screen-orientation, ionic-native

I want to detect the device orientation change event.
I need to change the image while orientation change in the device.

I tried some of the examples but it is not working at all.
I also tried the **screen-orientation** plugin but it also not working.

Plugin which I used

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

These are in my package.json.

```
"@ionic-native/app-preferences": "^4.18.0",
"@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.18.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that with the **screen-orientation** plugin, that you have:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) { }

...


this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(
   () => {
       console.log("Orientation changed to " + this.screenOrientation.type);
   }
);
```